# Using WordPress date query to compare a date against another value in the resultset

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WordPress date query to get a list of events, and want the currently ongoing events to show up.

My current query is:

```php
$date_query = [
    'key'   => 'eventDate', 
    'value' => $now, 
    'compare' => '>='
];
```

My database record has an eventDate, and an eventDuration (days). Ideally without altering the data set format, I would like my list to include all events which are currently ongoing.

It looks like 'key' cannot be anything other than a field name, so I can't make it add eventDate and eventDuration there - but is there any way in 'value' to access another resultset field, so I could do something like $now - 'eventDuration'?

I've looked for wants to include the duration in the key and in the value, but found no valid way.

I could alter the data model to include an eventEndDate, but I am hoping to avoid changing the model for my current users.

Comment: What is $now ? Assuming its current date what format it is ? Here is a basic example how your query should look like $args = array( 'post_type'  => 'your_post_type', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key'     => 'eventDate', 'value'   => '2023-06-05', 'compare' => '>=', 'type'    => 'DATE', ), ), );

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. $now is todays date. What I am looking for is a way of comparing eventDate, but not with a single value, I want to compare it with todays date minus the value in another column eventDays. I think this is probably not possible as it looks like the value parameter is evaluated before the resultset is returned, so it would have no access to other columns in the data.  I think Im just going to alter my custom_post to hold an endDate as well.